# Error recaptcha google V3 return null

Tags: php, javascript, html, recaptcha

He seguido la documentacion de google y funciona correctamente en el localhost, el problema es al subirlo al host donde esta alojada la pagina, al enviar el formulario el valor del captcha me retorna null.

Fragmento de codigo que va en el head en el html:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'></script>
```

Fragmento de codigo que va en el form

```
    <div class="agileits_mail_grid_right1 agile_mail_grid_right1">
                    <form action="send-contact.php" method="post" target="_blank">
                        <span>
                            <i>Nombre</i>
                            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required="">
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <i>Correo</i>
                            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Correo" required="">
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <i>Asunto</i>
                            <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Asunto" required="">
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <i>Mensaje</i>
                            <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Mensaje" required=""></textarea>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"><br>
                        <div class="w3_submit">
                            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Enviar">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Fragmento de codigo del script

```
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {action: 
    'action_name'})
    .then(function(token) {
    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
     });
      });
 </script>
```

Claves del sitio y clave secretas estan definidas como constantes en un archivo config.php

Fragmentos de codigos php

```
class Captcha{

public function getCaptcha($SecretKey)
{
    $Respuesta=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response={$SecretKey}");
    $Retorno=json_decode($Respuesta);
    return $Retorno;
    }
 }
```

Archivo php que deberia recibir los datos del captcha y del form

```
include("getcaptcha.php");

  $ObjCaptcha=new Captcha();
   $Retorno=$ObjCaptcha->getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    var_dump ($Retorno);
```

Anexo imagenes de la respuesta en local
[image: Respuesta favorable si el usuario pasa el captcha]

[image: Respuesta desfavorable si el usuario no pasa el captcha]
Anexo imagen de respuesta en el host[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Pusiste tu archivo `config.php` en el sitio remoto? ¿Verificaste que está tomando bien la API KEY por ejemplo?

Comment: Sugiero que [vuelvas a verificar aquí todos los pasos](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/reCAPTCHA/index.html#0). No sé si por ejemplo al configurar pusiste solamente `localhost`, creo que debes poner tu dominio remoto (paso 3). Y verifica cada cosa de nuevo.

Comment: Si añadi el archivo config en el host, y tambien verifique lo del sitio por la url de la web, como asi que este tomando bien la API KEY?

Comment: Aquí: `$Respuesta=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response={$SecretKey}");` en lugar de `SECRET_KEY` supongo que estás poniendo el valor que recibiste de Google para usar reCaptcha.

Comment: Claro el SECRET_KEY esta definida como una constante en el archivo config.php  <?php
define('SITE_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

define('SECRET_KEY','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
 ?> las x son para no mostrar la clave

Comment: Es extraño que funcione en local y no en el servidor. ¿Agregaste todos los archivos al servidor seguro? Algo debe faltar a nivel de archivos o a nivel de validación del servidor en tu consola de reCaptcha.

Comment: Los agregue todos y verifique uno por uno, no entiendo es por que retorna nul, he probado tantas veces que me aprendi el codigo de memoria

Comment: Aunque realmente tu código es un poco *lío*, por ejemplo, no entiendo por qué le pasas `$SecretKey` a esta función: `getCaptcha($SecretKey)` ¿?  ¿Acaso no declaraste `SECRET KEY` en una constante. Tienes una mezcla extraña ahí. ¿Por qué no pruebas de una forma más simple primero, [mira este tutorial](https://stevencotterill.co.uk/blog/adding-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form/), en la parte titulada *Server side integration*. El uso de la clase que implementas me parece confuso. Captura los valores como se indica ahí y luego usa `file_get_contents`. Depura el POST también si fuera necesario.

Comment: Puedes creer que he copiado todo tal cual (solo cambiando la secret y la site key) y aun asi me sigue retornando un null?

Comment: Amigo muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, ya encontre la solucion el problema era el host, pasamos la web a su host (puesto que estaba en el de la compañia mientras desarrollaba) y hay si funciono muchas gracias por tu atencion.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en tu llamada de `file_get_contentens()` en el último parámetro.
Debería de ser así:

```
$Respuesta=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response=".$SecretKey);
```

Comment: Discula, pero no entiendo la diferéncia entre tu respuesta y el código original, ¿estás seguro que esto soluciona el problema? Si es así, deberías explicar tu razonamiento y cómo es que esto lo soluciona. Por mi parte debo decir que no hay diferencia entre poner la variable entre {} dentro de la cadena y concatenada con . fuera de ella.